# duplicators for HDs installation

Tags: windows-7

I hope to install many HDs at the same time. I have tried the network solution but it's very slow so I'm looking for a special device to clone HDs multiple drives at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

There are several manufacturers of drive duplicators. Here are a few:

- [Kanguru](https://www.kanguru.com/index.php/duplicators/hd-duplicators)
- [ICS](http://www.ics-iq.com/SearchResults.asp?Cat=103)
- [Addonics](http://www.addonics.com/products/duplicator/hdd_duplicator.asp)

A couple of dealers:

- [Provantage](http://www.provantage.com/scripts/search.dll?QUERY=drive+duplicator&Submit.x=0&Submit.y=0)
- [TigerDirect](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CC4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.tigerdirect.com%2Fapplications%2Fcategory%2Fcategory_slc.asp%3FCatId%3D1264%26name%3DHard%2520Drive%2520Duplicators&ei=Ncq1TKPtAcL7lwfc7sTtBQ&usg=AFQjCNFQO_HKMyZwZJZRXcYd7gYd4buOxQ&sig2=lSjNg2amxQncu88-R1doHA)

[image: Kanguru 12HD-SATA]

Answer (score 0):

Would something like `Norton Ghost` or `Acronis TrueImage` work for you?  They can make an image of a HD using regular PC.